# How can I minimize the distance between a symbol and a word above that?

Tags: symbols

I use the command `\underset` to write a symbol or word below of a symbol. For instance, `$\underset{\mbox{iso}}{\cong}$`, but the distance between them looks too big. How can I minimize that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Skillmon : thank you very much! And I will write the next question with the appropiate beginning and the end (I am sorry for this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the height of the `\hbox{iso}` to 0pt via `\smash`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
$\underset{\smash{\hbox{iso}}}{\cong}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @joseabp91 perhaps you shouldn't accept my answer right now. There is a good chance that in the next few hours there will be a better answer. If that's not the case you can accept mine.

Comment: I have accepted it as I have found the thing which I was searching in your answer